# Create highstock using AJAX/JSON

Tags: ajax, json, angularjs

I build a highstock using AngularJs,

This is the code currently look like http://jsfiddle.net/j06ivy/r88yszk0/

My question is how can I returns JSON data (http link) instead of put these data below in javascript code?

```
    $scope.chartConfig.series.push({
    id: 1,
    data: [
        [1147651200000, 23.15],
        [1147737600000, 23.01],
        [1147824000000, 22.73],
        [1147910400000, 22.83],
        [1147996800000, 22.56],
        [1148256000000, 22.88],
        [1148342400000, 22.79],
        [1148428800000, 23.50],
        [1148515200000, 23.74],
        [1148601600000, 23.72],
        [1148947200000, 23.15],
        [1149033600000, 22.65]
    ]
},   {
    id: 2,
    data: [
        [1147651200000, 25.15],
        [1147737600000, 25.01],
        [1147824000000, 25.73],
        [1147910400000, 25.83],
        [1147996800000, 25.56],
        [1148256000000, 25.88],
        [1148342400000, 25.79],
        [1148428800000, 25.50],
        [1148515200000, 26.74],
        [1148601600000, 26.72],
        [1148947200000, 26.15],
        [1149033600000, 26.65]
    ]

}

);
```

---

I try to build on my webserver

http://52.74.94.173/ivy-demo-project/highstock-json.html

I think if something wrong in here?

`$scope.chartConfig.series.push({
        data: jsonData
        });`

Answer (score 0):

you can use the $http service, here are the docs: [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

place your data in a json file, then you can access you file locally like so

```
$http.get("../relativePathTolocalJSON/mydata.json");
```

your file needs to be in a legal JSON format

Answer (score 0):

Your fiddle doesn't work because of several js errors - at least $http is not injected, missing parenthesis and your json file is not available from a domain other than yours.

Check [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/b5rqpoqg/1/) and make sure that your json file is available and contains an array with two data series for the chart.

```
$http.get('http://j06ivy.tw/public/chart-data.json').success(function (jsonData) {
    $scope.chartConfig.series.push({
        data: jsonData
    });
});
```